# Node red web page not loading

Tags: node-red

I´m working in a rs-485 power meter web telemetry interface using raspbian, node-red in a raspberry pi3. 
I used the modbus nodes. 
I was increasing my flows, testing and improving. It´worked fine until suddenly, the web interface started to show a loading problem.

I try to open node-red directly on the desktop using localhost:1880, it will not load.

It only loads the Node-Red logo (header) and the sidebar, but no nodes in the palette. It shows the "loading" gif but that is all. It also does not show my flows. After a while (lots of mins) the interface opens and then I can edit the flows, deploy and work with flows with no problems. This just happens when I try to open for the first time after powering on the raspberry pi... In the raspberry, I can see that the CPU is working a lot. Sometimes goes to 100%. The dashboard I've created stops to responds and lost connection.

I don't know if this is related to flow code, raspberry files, or my web browser.

Comment: Have you looked at the Node-RED logs? Node-RED can be slow to start on a Pi as it has to walk all the nodes and initialise them, especially if it's doing other things, e.g. start up X and a running a browser. The logs will indicate when it's finished loading

Comment: Apparently, I found the problem. It was related to the amount of libraries that are in the folder /home/pi/.node-red/lib/. In the menu in the upper right corner "= > import > library" many libraries would appear. I think it's a problem to have many libraries in this folder. The Web browser has difficulty loading all and hangs up for a few moments, until it loads. After deleting these libraries, which i´m not using, the web page instantly loaded! Even the raspberry pi is working without much processing load now.